# Using past simple in main clause with since - Is it correct?

Tags: grammar

I read an article on a website and found a sentence that I need to know whether it is correct or not.

Can we use simple past tense like in the following sentence (in bold). Is it correct? Don't they have to use present perfect tense if they use "since" because of a non-specific time started in the past and still contines?

---

A set of four tiny combs from the Polynesian kingdom Tonga might be among the world's oldest tattoo kits.

The tools had been sitting in storage in an Australian university for decades. A team of researchers recently reassessed the artifacts and found that the combs — two of which are made from human bone — are 2,700 years old.

Archaeologists have known that tattooing ***was practiced in several cultures since prehistory***. Mummies from Siberia to Egypt have been found with tattoos visible on their flesh. Ötzi the Iceman, a 5,000-year-old mummy found in the Alps, has dozens of tattoos on his body, which some researchers think were inked on for therapeutic purposes.

---

Comment: I'm not happy about 'Archeologists have known' without its own temporal phrase ('for a long time', 'since the 1920s' etc), even before we get that far. '... since prehistory' doesn't work!

Comment: I think there's a reasonable justification for using the simple past here because some of these cultures (like Ötzi the Iceman's) no longer exist. For example, you wouldn't say *tattooing has been practiced in Ötzi's culture since antiquity*; you need *was practiced* there.

Comment: I had typed the same thing @PeterShor said then sat on it while I went to work. Different dialects have different expectations as to how aspectual info is prioritized. SE tends to prioritize by person 1st, 2nd, 3rd, then the rest of the universe. And there isn't any great expectation of any of this. Southern English effectively reverses this and there is a very strong tendency to include aspectual info on the universe and 3rd persons. Hence Edwin's comment makes perfect sense in SE dialect, but would probably have to be explained to a Southerner.